# In AWS CloudFormation are booleans and strings of booleans interchangeable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am confused by how AWS CloudFormation treats booleans and *strings* of booleans.

For instance, are `'true'` and `true` (or `'false'` and `false`) logically equivalent as far as CloudFormation is concerned? I see examples of both cases in their Quick Start templates that lead me to think they are (even though I haven't found documentation of this one way or another).

For instance, in their template, [quickstart-compliance-common/templates/vpc-production.template](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-compliance-common/blob/d6964392ef2c666c68c560558b17157e1e135ff6/templates/vpc-production.template#L128), they define a variable, `pSupportsNatGateway`, of type "String" (even though its default is the *literal* value, `true`):

```
Parameters:
  ...
  pSupportsNatGateway:
    Description: Specifies whether this region supports NAT Gateway (this value is
      determined by the main stack if it is invoked from there)
    Type: String
    Default: true
```

Then, in a [condition](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-compliance-common/blob/d6964392ef2c666c68c560558b17157e1e135ff6/templates/vpc-production.template#L176) later in the template, that parameter (presumably a String) is compared to the *literal* value, `true`.

```
Conditions:
  ...
  cSupportsNatGateway:
    !Equals
    - true
    - !Ref pSupportsNatGateway
```

My question is, how does CloudFormation compare literal values and *strings* of those values? Where is this defined in the AWS documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where this is documented, but **yes**! It does appear that literal booleans (or numbers) and their string values are equivalent as far as CloudFormation is concerned.

I created a minimal CloudFormation template to test this:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Test CloudFormation template

Parameters:

  pCreateCluster:
    Description: To create or not create?
    Type: String
    Default: 'true'
    AllowedValues:
    - 'true'
    - 'false'

Conditions:
  CreateClusterConditionTrue1:
    !Equals
    - !Ref pCreateCluster
    - 'true'

  CreateClusterConditionTrue2:
    !Equals
    - !Ref pCreateCluster
    - true

  CreateClusterConditionFalse1:
    !Equals
    - !Ref pCreateCluster
    - 'false'

  CreateClusterConditionFalse2:
    !Equals
    - !Ref pCreateCluster
    - false

Resources:

  rFargateCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Condition: CreateClusterConditionTrue1
    Properties:
      ClusterName: "my-test-cluster"

Outputs:
  CreateClusterConditionTrue1:
    Value:
      !If
      - CreateClusterConditionTrue1
      - "The answer is True"
      - "The answer is False"
  CreateClusterConditionTrue2:
    Value:
      !If
      - CreateClusterConditionTrue2
      - "The answer is True"
      - "The answer is False"
  CreateClusterConditionFalse1:
    Value:
      !If
      - CreateClusterConditionFalse1
      - "The answer is True"
      - "The answer is False"
  CreateClusterConditionFalse2:
    Value:
      !If
      - CreateClusterConditionFalse2
      - "The answer is True"
      - "The answer is False"
...
```

And the results demonstrate that they are in fact equivalent:

```
Key                             Value
CreateClusterConditionTrue1     The answer is True      
CreateClusterConditionTrue2     The answer is True      
CreateClusterConditionFalse2    The answer is False     
CreateClusterConditionFalse1    The answer is False
```